# Visual Studio 2019 WSDL how to use <any> element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, onvif

I'm consumning this ONVIF service: https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl using Visual Studio 2019, which automatically generates a client wrapper from the WSDL file.

I cannot figure out how to use the 'Extension' element of OSDTextConfiguration to add an element to OSDTextConfiguration which has not been specified in the WSDL.

```
<xs:complexType name="OSDTextConfiguration">
   ...
   <xs:element name="Extension" type="tt:OSDTextConfigurationExtension" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="OSDTextConfigurationExtension">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>   <!-- first Vendor then ONVIF -->
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is the full file where the types are defined:
https://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd?ccc393&ccc393

Visual Studio defined the code below, and I guess I should be able to use XmlAnyElementAttribute() to add my element, but I do not know how to do it. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public partial class OSDConfigurationExtension : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
    get {
        return this.anyField;
    }
    set {
        this.anyField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Any");
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
    get {
        return this.anyAttrField;
    }
    set {
        this.anyAttrField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("AnyAttr");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this and post it here in case it's useful to someone else. The function below inserts an element 'IsPersistent' with value '0' or '1'.

```
  internal static void SetOverlayPersistent(bool isPesistent, OSDConfiguration osd)
  {
     osd.Extension = new OSDConfigurationExtension();
     System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
     System.Xml.XmlElement elem = xmlDoc2.CreateElement("IsPersistent", "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema");
     elem.InnerText = isPesistent ? "1" : "0";
     osd.Extension.Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[1];
     osd.Extension.Any[0] = elem;
  }
```